# MS Access Delete query based on combobox

Tags: sql, forms, combobox

I have a table with a bunch of different fields. One is named period.

The period is not part of the raw data but I run a query when I import new data to the database that gives each record a period.

Now I need a delete query that will delete all the records that have the same period as what is selected in a combobox.

The values in the combobox come from a calendar table that contain all the possible values that could be in that period column at any time.

This is the basic query i thought would solve this issue but it tells me it is going to delete 0 rows every time I run it:

```
DELETE *  
FROM PlanTemp  
WHERE PlanTemp.period = Forms![Plan Form]!Combo163;
```

Comment: Is your combo box bound to the proper column?  Sometimes you may have a KEY column that isn't showing up. So when you are reading the value, it is getting some other value than what you think it is getting.

Comment: Instead of a query, try running the query as a command, so you can set a breakpoint and see what value is getting sent to the query.   DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tblDEL WHERE tblDEL.number = " & Forms![form 1]!Combo0)

Comment: Not gonna lie im very new to access so I don't know how to run it as a command, but in the combobox properties the row source selects a key field (ID) as well as the field with the values i want, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: If you don't need the key field, just remove it.  Look at the "PROPERTIES" section and look at the column names.  Ether remove it there, or from your QUERY source.  You can also look at the Data section of the properties, and change your BOUND column, to Column 2... or whatever holds the data you want to use.

Comment: Wow, so much simpler than i was ever aware. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the key field, just remove it.

Look at the "PROPERTIES" section and look at the column names.

Ether remove it there, or from your QUERY source.

You can also look at the Data section of the properties, and change your BOUND column, to Column 2... or whatever holds the data you want to use.